# How do I make my JSON file readable in my pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas

Here is my code:

```
with open(r'unique_columns.json', 'r') as f:
    config = json.load(f)

unique_col_comb = config['Unique_Column_Combination']['TABLE_NAME']

df = pd.read_csv(f's3://path/to/file.csv', sep='|')
df_unique = df.set_index([unique_col_comb]).index.is_unique
print(df_unique)
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Unique_Column_Combination":
    {
        "TABLE_NAME": "COL1, COL2, COL3"
    }

}
```

I get the error:

`KeyError: "None of ['COL1, COL2, COL3'] are in the columns"`

But when I actually write out the columns in `df_unique`, the code works:

```
df_unique = df.set_index(['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3']).index.is_unique
>>True
```

I think I need to add an extra quote (") to the end of each column name in my JSON file but then it won't be in proper JSON format. Can I add it in the python code? Or do I need to convert my JSON dictionary to a python list?

Comment: Please include a sample of actually readable data. It doesn't have to be real, just something that will actually be usable by the code. Please read [mre].

Answer (score 2):

`"COL1, COL2, COL3"` is a single string. You should probably split it into three column names with `unique_col_comb.split()`

Comment: thanks for your response. i added that here `df_unique = df.set_index([unique_col_comb.split()]).index.is_unique` but now i'm getting the error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 2 rows, received array of length 3`. i thought it would read the 3 columns individually

Comment: nevermind i see the issue, it prints out the columns like this: `['COL1,', 'COL2,', 'COL3,']` so there is an extra comma i have to get rid of

Comment: i changed it to `df_unique = df.set_index([unique_col_comb.split(", ")]).index.is_unique` and it's still giving the same error `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected 2 rows, received array of length 3` i think i have to figure something else out...

Comment: Ah, you don't need the square brackets around the split, because the output of that is a list already.

Comment: oh my gosh that was the issue! you were right! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The json does not decompose into what would be a dataframe.

Here is an example of json that can be read:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

json_string = """
{
  "employees": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "john@email.com",
      "phone": "555-555-5555"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "email": "jane@email.com", 
      "phone": "444-444-4444"
    }
  ]
}
"""

j = json.loads(json_string)

df = pd.DataFrame(j['employees'])
print(df)
```

I didn't mention `df.read_json()` in the example because this part worked and it is the format of the `json` that failed.

In your example this json would work if square brackets added for example:

```
{
    "Unique_Column_Combination":[
    {
        "TABLE_NAME": "COL1, COL2, COL3"
    }
    ]
}
```

to give this:

```
         TABLE_NAME
0  COL1, COL2, COL3
```

Comment: now it's saying `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @Lilcodemuffin,  it depends on the structure of the data and what you want to achieve. In the example code, that modified the given JSON there is only one column (called "TABLE_NAME")... so perhaps better to format like in the example in the top half of the answer...